# I pressed the sleep button on my keyboard and now I can't wake up my computer

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, sleep

My motherboard is the 970 extreme 4 and the lights and fans turn on but my keyboard and monitor aren't working.  My monitor says it has no signal and the keyboard light doesn't turn on. I've tried unplugging it and restarting it and pressing the esc button but no luck. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try holding the power button for 4 or 5 seconds and pressing it again?

Comment: Does the system POST?  What beeps do you hear when turning it?